# Relationship between the cocountable and standard topologies on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Where can I find a proof of the fact that the cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is coarser than, finer than, or not comparable with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$? For a seemingly standard fact I cannot find a reference to a proof anywhere...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "coarser"? The topologies, I think, are incomparable.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is open in the standard topology but not the co-countable topology. The irrationals are open in the co-countable topology but not the standard topology.

Comment: I’d be a little surprised to find a reference for something that is basically a routine beginning exercise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'd be a little surprised to find a beginning exercising asking you to prove something that isn't true. Okay, I wouldn't, but only because publishing can be a crap shoot in terms of quality. :)

Comment: The co-finite topology on $\mathbb R$ is coarser than the standard topology, however.

Comment: @Thomas: Obviously I’m going by the text of the question, not the title (which I’ve now fixed to match the question).

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed the edit. The original question matched the title. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: Ah, I see; I never saw the original version.

Answer (score 4):

Denote the cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathcal{T}$, and denote the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathcal{S}$. There exists $S \in \mathcal{S}$ with $S \notin \mathcal{T}$; for example, $(0, 1)$ is open in $\mathcal{S}$, but its complement is not countable. Similarly, there exists $T \in \mathcal{T}$ with $T \notin \mathcal{S}$; for example, consider $T = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1/n\text{ }|\text{ }n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. $T$ clearly has countable complement, so $T \in \mathcal{T}$. However, $T$ is not open in the standard topology; the point $0$ is in $T$ but all neighborhoods of $0$ intersect an element of $T^c$. Thus, neither $\mathcal{S}$ nor $\mathcal{T}$ is a subset of the other, so they are not comparable.